# Nonzero subspace that is invariant under any operator cannot be proper?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is not for homework, and I would **just a like a hint please**.  The question asks

> Prove or give a counterexample: If $U$ is a subspace of $V$ that is invariant under every operator on $V$, then $U = \{ 0 \}$ or $U = V$.

In the question, $V$ is finite dimensional.  My gut feeling is that this claim is true, so I tried to begin a proof.  I began by assuming $U \neq \{ 0 \}$.  I want to try to exploit the fact that $U$ is invariant under every operator to try and force every basis vector of $V$ into $U$.  I would like **just a hint please**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: assume $U\ne\{0\}$ and $U\ne V$; then if $\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ is a basis for $U$, you can extend it to a basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_k,u_{k+1},\dots,u_n\}$ of $V$. You can define a linear map $V\to V$ by telling the action on a basis. Can you make $f$ that shows $U$ is not $f$-invariant?

Note: you don't need finite dimensionality, but of course the proof in the non finite dimensional case requires the axiom of choice.

---

#### Details (added after accept)

We know that $0<\dim U=k<\dim V=n$, so in the argument we *do* have $u_1$ and $u_{k+1}$. Thus the linear map $f\colon V\to V$ defined by
$$
f(u_i)=\begin{cases}
u_{k+1} & \text{if $i=1$}\\
0 & \text{if $1<i<n$}
\end{cases}
$$
shows $U$ is not $f$-invariant.

The same idea can be used in the general case: take a non-zero vector $u\in U$ and extend it to a basis $B$ of $U$; now take $v\notin U$ and extend $B\cup\{v\}$ to a basis $C$ of $V$ (this is possible using Zorn's lemma). Then define the linear map $f\colon V\to V$ by $f(u)=v$ and $f(w)=0$ for $w\in C$, $w\ne u$.

Another possibility is to define $f(u_i)=u_{i+1}$ for $1\le i<n$ and $f(u_n)=u_1$. Since $f(u_k)=u_{k+1}\notin U$, $U$ is not $f$-invariant.

Comment: How about $T(u_i) = u_{i+1}$ (and $T(u_n) = u_1$)?

Comment: @tylerc0816 That's a possibility; a simpler one is $T(u_1)=u_{k+1}$ and $T(u_i)=0$ for $i>1$. This emphasizes the fact that $u_1$ exists (because $U\ne\{0\}$) and $u_{k+1}$ exists (because $U\ne V$).

Comment: Is there another way to prove it without assuming that U≠V.

Comment: @user2162882 What do you mean? The thesis is that either $U=V$ or $U=\{0\}$. So I assume $U\ne V$ and $U\ne\{0\}$ and get a contradiction. Or, better, that subspaces different from $\{0\}$ and $V$ are not $f$-invariant for all $f$.

Comment: What if the thesis didn't include the U = V part?

Comment: @user2162882 I can't understand.

Comment: @user2162882 Then the only case when $U$ is $f$-invariant is when $k=n$, hence we come to the conclusion that $U=V$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* For any $x \ne 0$ and $y$ in $V$ there is an operator $A$ with $Ax = y$.